# Как экспортировать SarePoint List в .xlsx файл

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, microsoft-api

Как из кода c# экспортировать SharePoint List в .xlsx файл? В самом SharePoint это можно сделать в ручную. Есть ли способ получить аналогичный результат, только через код c#? Пытался делать c библиотекой CSOM, но экспортится много непонятных и не нужных полей.

Comment: Прошерстил весь интернет и нашел для себя подходящим решением подключить эксель файл к шарпоинту (используя .iqy) и из кода в нужный момент обновлять таблицу. Может кому-нибудь подойдет такой вариант